# Why my pycurl is not compiled against Openssl?

Tags: python, linux, pycurl, kali-linux

I'm trying to run on kali linux 2020 wfuzz, but i got this error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/wfuzz-3.1.0-py3.9.egg/wfuzz/__init__.py:34: UserWarning:Pycurl is not compiled against Openssl. Wfuzz might not work correctly when fuzzing SSL sites. Check Wfuzz's documentation for more information.
```

I tried this too but it doesn't work :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev
mkdir ~/python-pycurl-openssl
cd ~/python-pycurl-openssl
sudo apt-get source python-pycurl
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pycurl -y
```

Any idea?

Comment: The question in the title, why, you'd have to raise as a bug at Kali linux. I don't think we can help you with the why.

Comment: We might be able to help you fix the build though. When you say it doesn't work, do you mean the build fails - with what error? - or that the built Pycurl still doesn't use OpenSSL? Does the system libcurl use OpenSSL? It's possible that curl was built against GnuTLS only and Pycurl doesn't like that for whatever reason.